# Content Security Policy not loading content over HTTPS

Tags: php, html, https, content-security-policy

I am using Content Security Policy and I am having trouble loading stylesheets, images and javascript over HTTPS

It all works fine over HTTP but as soon I get a page over HTTPS I get errors in the Chrome console like this

> Refused to load the stylesheet
>   'http://my-domain/public/css/bootstrap.min.css' because it violates
>   the following Content Security Policy directive: "style-src 'self'
>   https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com https://ajax.googleapis.com
>   https://fonts.googleapis.com
>   'nonce-SLkcvNDK0InbqoywRHBvWE9qYBDXLlmu'".        login: 1

which points to

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Here is how my headers are created

```
// Set a sample rule
$csp_rules = "default-src 'self'; script-src 'self' 'nonce-".RANDOM."' https://ajax.googleapis.com https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com https://connect.facebook.net; style-src 'self' https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com https://ajax.googleapis.com https://fonts.googleapis.com 'nonce-".RANDOM."'; font-src 'self' https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com https://fonts.gstatic.com; img-src 'self' https://ajax.googleapis.com; frame-src https://s-static.ak.facebook.com https://www.facebook.com;";

foreach (array("X-WebKit-CSP", "X-Content-Security-Policy", "Content-Security-Policy") as $csp){
    header($csp . ": " . $csp_rules);
}

// Provides Clickjacking protection.
header('X-Frame-Options: deny');
// This header enables the Cross-site scripting (XSS) filter built into most recent web browsers.
header('X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block');
// Pevents Internet Explorer and Google Chrome from MIME-sniffing a response away from the declared content-type. 
header('X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff');
```

Do I need to add anything to the rule or could it be something else?

**EDIT:**

Here is how the stylesheet link looks like in the source

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://my-domain/public/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

Comment: Are you loading the CSS hardcoded by HTTP?

Comment: Updated question. Link uses HTTPS

Comment: What is the URL that your page is loaded from? Is that HTTPS?